# Multiple filter on line and reorder line

Tags: linux, perl, sed, awk, grep

My title is a bit confusing because I don't know how to express it in good english.

Here's my issue. I'm having a flat file formatted this way:

```
: name1 field1-1: field2:value1-2 field3:"value1-3"     field4:{"Value-1-4"}
: name2 field2-1: field2:"value2-2"      field4:{"Value-2-4"} field3:Value2-3
: name3 field3-1:  field3:{"Value-3-3"}  field2:value3-2   field4:value3-4
```

So you can see that it's not a nice file because field does not appear in the same order they can be with different type of value sometimes and more over they are sometime missing. The orginal file is also 5 to 20 fields long.

Now here's what I want to have in the end:

```
: name1 field2:value1-2 field4:{"Value-1-4"}      
: name2 field2:"value2-2" field4:{"Value-2-4"}
: name3 field2:value3-2 field4:value3-4
```

So I know the field I want in the final file and I know the precise order I want them to appear.

I tried something like

```
sed "s/(field1:.*)|(field2:.*)/\2\1/g"
```

I know it's not the right synthax but it's for readability. But it do not work because the first match is the only to match that happen and the other group can't match.

I guess what I want to do is possible with a lot of `awk`, but I really don't know how I can do it. I really prefer to use `bash`, `sed`, `awk` and `grep` but if I have no choice I can I can deal with a bit of `Perl`

**EDIT:** I may give a simple example but the real file has really different fields name

Good night and thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way with `awk`:

#### Script.awk:

```
{
    split ($0,ary,/ /); 
    printf "%s %s ", ary[1],ary[2]; 
    for (i=3;i<=length(ary);i++) {
        if (ary[i] ~ /^field[2,4]:/) { 
            printf "%s ",ary[i]
        }
    }
    print "" 
}
```

#### Output:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
: name1 field1-1: field2:value1-2 field3:"value1-3"     field4:{"Value-1-4"}
: name2 field2-1: field2:"value2-2"      field4:{"Value-2-4"} field3:Value2-3
: name3 field3-1:  field3:{"Value-3-3"}  field2:value3-2   field4:value3-4

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -f script.awk file
: name1 field2:value1-2 field4:{"Value-1-4"}
: name2 field2:"value2-2" field4:{"Value-2-4"}
: name3 field2:value3-2 field4:value3-4
```

Comment: As my original file is much more complicate than the example I'll try to adapt it but i'm sure I can :-)

Comment: Sure, you will probably have to play around with the `if` conditional.

Answer (score 4):

Split each line by space, print first two columns, and these that start with `field[24]:`

```
perl -anE 'say join " ", @F[0,1], grep /^field[24]:/, @F' file
```

Comment: +1 I kind of used your logic for my `awk` solution, but this is a great answer.

Comment: Can I use this one with multiple pattern in grep like : grep /^field[24]:\|categorie\|tennis/ ? because if I can it's f$$$$$$ great

Comment: I guess that should be `grep /^(field[24]|categorie|tennis):/`, so yes, you can.

Answer (score 1):

Some sed:

```
sed -e 's/^\(: [^ ]*\)\(.*\)\(field4:[^ ]*\)/\1 \3REMOVE \2/' \
    -e 's/^\(: [^ ]*\)\(.*\)\(field2:[^ ]*\)/\1 \3 \2/'       \
    -e 's/REMOVE.*//' input
```

When the input line is:

```
: name1 field1-1: field2:value1-2 field3:"value1-3"     field4:{"Value-1-4"}
```

The first expression moves field4 to the first column after the name and appends REMOVE:

```
: name1 field4:{"Value-1-4"}REMOVE  field1-1: field2:value1-2 field3:"value1-3
```

The second expression moves field2 to the first column:

```
: name1 field2:value1-2 field4:{"Value-1-4"}REMOVE  field1-1:  field3:"value1-3"
```

And the third one deletes from REMOVE to the end:

```
: name1 field2:value1-2  field4:{"Value-1-4"}
```

Comment: That would be the solution I choose if my original file was as simple as my example, but in my case I think awk and perl are the only solution.